# Azure devOps repo is not synced with my git repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos, git-repo

My git repo has been connected to my project repo in azure devops. Later on,  I created a new branch in my git repo. But I don't see this new branch in my azure repo. Shouldn't they be synced?

Update: Eventually, I figured out that azure DevOps repo doesn't
get synced with git repo, automatically. We need to create a pipeline for this purpose. Here you can find the solution: https://faun.pub/how-to-synchronize-azure-repos-with-external-git-repos-70ff92e51c63

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: No they shouldn't. You have to push first.

Can you clarify what you mean by your git repo?
Is it a folder on your pc where you have your code and a ".git" folder?
Is it a space on a page like github or git lab?

Also, what does "connected" mean ?

Explanation (based on some guesses on the points above):

If you have just a local folder, then be aware that git is not a "synchronization" tool like dropbox or onedrive, even though visual studio makes it look like so (That's bad design!). There are normally some manual steps to do before you will see your code in azure. And some of those need to be re-done every time you change something (at least stage, commit, push). The references below may help you. Note that your local .git folder is often called the "local repository" and your code your "working copy", while your Azure space is the "remote".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pushing?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/git/git_basic_concepts.htm
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-the-basics-of-git-in-under-10-minutes-da548267cc91/

Git is difficult in the beginning, but don't let yourself be discouraged, it will get easier!

Comment: I am not new in git, but I am new in azure devops. I meant the git repo in GitHub, not local folder in my pc. I thought whatever I see in my githup repo (and of course committed and pushed) should be reflected in my azure project repo. My git repo is primary and my azure repo is secondary. Thanks for your response anyway.